# How to add an OpenAPI Annotation to a C# record?

Tags: c#, openapi

I'm trying to add the following OpenApi annotations to a simple C# record:

```
    public record Request(
        [OpenApiProperty(Description = "AA")]
        string ClientId,
        [OpenApiProperty(Description = "BBB")]
        string ClientSecret);
```

But it's not finding this property `[OpenApiProperty(..)]`.

[image]

- Is this the correct property/annotation to decorate my params?
- Where is this found?

I tried adding: `<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="6.5.0" />` but still the code doesn't compile.

Anyone have any clues/suggestions, please?

Comment: The annotations package you're referring to looks at 'Swagger...' attributes, e.g. `[SwaggerOperation(Summary = "Foo")]`, `[SwaggerResponse(400, "The index parameter is negative")]`, `[SwaggerSchema(Description = "My super duper data")]`

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson thank you for the reply. Are you saying that the package _I should be using_ is `[SwaggerXXX]` ? or that the nuget package i referenced would be for `[SwaggerXXX]` and  therefore I should be using a _different_ package for `[OpenApiProperty]`?

Comment: Note: Whatever attribute you end up using, the way you wrote it in your record applies the attribute to the record's **constructor parameter**. To make the attribute apply to the **generated property** like intended, you must prepend the attribute name with `property:` target like this: `record A([property: YourAttribute(Description = "AA")] string ClientId);`

Comment: Reference for record attribute targets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#positional-syntax-for-property-definition

Comment: @Orion dude. DUDE! that was it. 

Answer (score 0):

Based on what @orion said in the OP comments, it was this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Query to retrieve a token.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ClientId">Your unique ClientId</param>
/// <param name="ClientSecret">The secret associated with your ClientId</param>
public record Query(string ClientId, string ClientSecret);
```

Just add the XML comments and the swagger generator actually pics it up!

-- or another way ---

```
public record Query(
    [property: OpenApiProperty(Description = "Your unique ClientId")]
    string ClientId, 

    [property: OpenApiProperty(Description = "The secret associated with your ClientId")]
    string ClientSecret);
```

Comment: What about using attributes targeted to properties instead of XML comments, like you originally wanted in your question? My suggestion and link talks about using attributes the right way, I didn't even know Swagger can pick up XML comments.

Comment: I prefer to use comments because they are "out of the way" when I read the actual `record` line. Also, the `JsonPropertyName` doesn't help with OpenAPI/Swagger documentation - it's more for JSON key names (which I use when I need to have a specific schema requirement which breaks my naming convention(s) )

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you to specifically use the attribute `JsonPropertyName`, I was just pointing at the way to apply the attribute to a property: in your case, it would be `[property: OpenApiProperty(Description = "AA")] string ClientId` - note the `property:` before the attr name that makes all the difference. If you prefer to use XML comments, that's ok.

Comment: I might update my answer to include BOTH your suggestions